What is the outcome of this endgame with best play?
I saw an endgame like this:
[title "Black to move"]
[fen "4k3/4p3/7K/8/8/8/P4R2/r7 w - - 0 1"]

Suppose I'm playing as black. What would be the outcome of this game assuming best play from both sides? I'm not too good at chess, so I would greatly appreciate a step-by-step walkthrough, and the idea behind it.

https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=4k3/4p3/7K/8/8/8/P4R2/r7_w_-_-_0_1 It's a tablebase draw.

(Small correction, the FEN above should have black to move instead of white. Still a tablebase draw.)
